How to Join Organization data and funding_rounds data from Crunchbase (Search API)
I have Organiztional  payload data from Crunchbase API as
{
    "field_ids": [
        "acquirer_identifier",
        "aliases",
        "categories",
        "valuation",
        "category_groups",
        "closed_on",
        "company_type",
        "contact_email",
        "created_at",
        "delisted_on",
        "demo_days",
        "description",
        "diversity_spotlights",
        "entity_def_id",
        "equity_funding_total",
        "exited_on",
        "facebook",
        "facet_ids",
        "founded_on",
        "founder_identifiers",
        "funding_stage",
        "funding_total",
        "funds_total",
        "hub_tags",
        "identifier",
        "image_id",
        "image_url",
        "investor_identifiers",
        "investor_stage",
        "investor_type",
        "ipo_status",
        "last_equity_funding_total",
        "last_equity_funding_type",
        "last_funding_at",
        "last_funding_total",
        "last_funding_type",
        "layout_id",
        "legal_name",
        "linkedin",
        "listed_stock_symbol",
        "location_group_identifiers",
        "location_identifiers",
        "name",
        "num_acquisitions",
        "num_alumni",
        "num_articles",
        "num_current_advisor_positions",
        "num_current_positions",
        "num_diversity_spotlight_investments",
        "num_employees_enum",
        "num_enrollments",
        "num_event_appearances",
        "num_exits",
        "num_exits_ipo",
        "num_founder_alumni",
        "num_founders",
        "num_funding_rounds",
        "num_funds",
        "num_investments",
        "num_investors",
        "num_lead_investments",
        "num_lead_investors",
        "num_past_positions",
        "num_portfolio_organizations",
        "num_sub_organizations",
        "operating_status",
        "override_layout_id",
        "owner_identifier",
        "permalink",
        "permalink_aliases",
        "phone_number",
        "program_application_deadline",
        "program_duration",
        "program_type",
        "rank_delta_d30",
        "rank_delta_d7",
        "rank_delta_d90",
        "rank_org",
        "rank_principal",
        "revenue_range",
        "school_method",
        "school_program",
        "school_type",
        "short_description",
        "status",
        "stock_exchange_symbol",
        "stock_symbol",
        "twitter",
        "updated_at",
        "uuid",
        "valuation",
        "valuation_date",
        "website",
        "website_url",
        "went_public_on"
    
    ],
    "query": [
        {
        //    "type": "predicate",
       //     "field_id": "website_url",
        //   "operator_id": "domain_eq",
         //   "values": [
         //       "arena.com"
          //  ]
          "type": "predicate",
            "field_id": "website_url",
            "operator_id": "domain_eq",
            "values": [
                "arena.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "order": [
        {
            "field_id": "updated_at",
            "sort": "desc",
            "nulls": "last"
        }
    ],
    "limit": 1
}

and my funding_round API AS
{
    "field_ids": [
        "announced_on",
    "closed_on",
    "created_at",
    "entity_def_id",
    "funded_organization_categories",
    "funded_organization_description",
    "funded_organization_diversity_spotlights",
    "funded_organization_funding_stage",
    "funded_organization_funding_total",
    "funded_organization_identifier",
    "funded_organization_location",
    "funded_organization_revenue_range",
    "identifier",
    "image_id",
    "investment_stage",
    "investment_type",
    "investor_identifiers",
    "is_equity",
    "lead_investor_identifiers",
    "money_raised",
    "name",
    "num_investors",
    "num_partners",
    "permalink",
    "post_money_valuation",
    "pre_money_valuation",
    "rank_funding_round",
    "short_description",
    "target_money_raised",
    "updated_at",
    "uuid"
    ],
    "query": [
        {
            "type": "predicate",
            "field_id": "funded_organization_identifier",
            "operator_id": "eq",
            "values": [
                "arena"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "limit": 20
}

How to join both data, their UUID are diffrent, am I missing a column here?
